# How to copy this class if it contains the same base class as the one I am assigning to?

Tags: c#

```
class ClassA
{

}

class ClassB : ClassA
{
    // it has its set of properties
}

class ClassC : ClassA
{

}


ClassB b = Factory.LoadB();

ClassC c = b as ClassA;  // doesn't work
```

is it possible to initiaze the instance c with the values from b?  i.e. initialize it so that all the properties from ClassA are set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in way to do this.

You'll need to write a function that assigns properties by hand.
You could also write a function that assigns properties using Reflection, but that would be needlessly slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a constructor like:

```
class ClassC: ClassA
{
    public ClassC(ClassB initial_value)
    {
        // Copy data here
    }
}

ClassC c = new ClassC(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this because `ClassC` is not a `ClassA`

```
ClassB b = Factory.LoadB();  

ClassA a = b as ClassA; // this is ok, because ClassB is type of ClassA

ClassC c = a; // a is a ClassA, but is not a type of ClassC
```